# Prove that there is no positive rational number a such that $a^2 = 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I solved a similar question $a^4 = 2$ but I didn't find it hard. This one is taking a lot of my time and I still don't understand how to solve this.

Here's what I have tried so far.

edit:

\begin{align}
a^2 &= 3 \\
a &= \left(\frac mn\right) \\ 
a^2 &= \left(\frac mn\right)^2 = 3 \\
m^2 &= 3n^2 \\
m &= 3p \\
m^2 &= (3p)^2 \\
9p^2 &= 3n^2
\end{align}

In another similar question $a^3 = 2$, I had to divide a common number from each side to finally solve the problem. But with this problem, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: How did you get $m=2p$? And how did that become $m^3=(2p)^2$?

Comment: Follow the same reasoning used to show that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.  This one is not any harder.

Comment: Do you understand why the step $m=2p$ was justified when you were solving $a^2=2$?

Comment: @kingW3 Because $m$ was even, so it was divisible by 2 for some integer $p$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Roarke Yes. The step $m=2p$ is infered. In this case it should be a different number. Can you figure out which one?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Oh god, I tried every way to solve this but didn't even try to remember what the definition meant. I assume that number to be 3?

Comment: @Roarke It is $3$. In fact the statement $m=3n^2$ means that $m$ is divisible by $3$. You had to assume that $n/m$ was in lowest terms then you derived a contradiction. Keep going and you got it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I did and got $(3p)^2 = 3n^2$. Then, $9p^2 = 3n^2$. I divided both sides with 3 and was left with $3p^2 = n^2$.

Comment: @Roarke hi is my answer helpful, or is it too confusing? I also added a bonus easy proof on the bottom

Comment: @Roarke glad my answer helped

Comment: "... and was left with $3p^2 = n^2$"  SO that means $n = 3q$ for some $q$ and you have both $m=3p$ and $n = 3q$ so... that's that.

Comment: @Roarke Right. You divide both sides by $3$ and conclude that both $n$ and $m$ are divisible by $3$, contradicting the fact that it was in lowest terms. Now try to generalize this to prove that $x^2=p$ is irrational for any prime number $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, make the straightforward assumption that $a= \frac mn$ with $m,n$ in lowest terms and they are integers. Thus, we get $(\frac mn)^2 = 3$, which soon becomes $m^2 = 3n^2$. Thus, $m^2$ is a multiple of $3$.

However, for $m^2$ to be a multiple of $3$, it needs to have an even number of factors of $3$. If it had an odd number of factors of $3$, you wouldn't get an integer for $m$ when you take the square root of $m^2$ because squares come in factors of even powers like $3^2$ or $2^2$. Thus, you must have an even number of $3$s in $m^2$, for it to be divisible by $3$. Now, when we take the square root of $m^2$ to get $m$, half of the $3$s disappear, but not all of them, so $m$ is divisible by $3$. Since $m$ is divisible by $3$, it can be expressed as $m=3p$. Thus, we get $(3p)^2 = 3n^2 \implies 3p^2 = n^2 $. Using the same logic as before, we can show that $n$ is divisible by $3$. This means that both $m,n$ are divisible by $3$, contradicting our initial assumption that $\frac mn$ is in lowest terms and shouldn't have any common factors besides $1$. Thus, there is no such $a = \frac mn$ with $m,n$ in lowest terms and integers such that $a^2=3$.

Here is a bonus easy proof. Rearrange $a^2=3$ to get $a^2-3=0$. By the rational root theorem, all the POSSIBLE rational roots of this polynomial are $a=-1,1,-3,3$. Let's see if any of these $a$ make $a^2=3$. Testing all these $a$, we see that none of these work, thus there is no RATIONAL $a$ such that $a^2=3$.

Comment: This is a basic question which is asked in innumerable "intro to proofs" style classes.  It has been asked-and-answered on this site a comparable number of times.  Rather than providing another answer to this duplicate question (and others like it), please consider helping the asker by taking a couple of minutes to look for those duplicates *before* you answer.  This ensures that the asker gets an answer to their question, and helps to keep the site organized.

Comment: Been staring at this for a few minutes now. I've got a few questions. What do you mean by when we take the square root of $m^2$ half of the 3s disappear? I'm very confused about this.

Comment: @Roarke $\sqrt{81} = \sqrt{3*3*3*3} = 3*3 = 9$, see half of them disappeared

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did search. I found a few duplicates as well. But they just provided answers straight up. A few of them had explained things too, but they were too hard for me to grasp. I spent over 2 hours just reading online before posting this question. Even went to Reddit, forums and searched the site. And multiple releated questions. My main goal was to know what do I need to do, and why do I need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The classic method known as "infinite descent". Assume from where you had : $m^2 = 3n^2 \implies m = 3k \implies n^2 = 3k^2 \implies n = 3p$, and it keeps going indefinitely with new pairs $(k,p)$ with $k < m, p < n$ and both are multiple of $3$ which is impossible. Thus there is no $(m,n)$ which satisfies the equation. So $\sqrt{3}$ must be irrational.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$ m^2 = 3n^2  \text{,}  $$ we know $3$ divides $m$, so $m = 3 m_1$
$$  9 m_1^2 = 3 n^2  $$
$$  3 m_1^2 = n^2  $$
This tells us $3$ divides $n$.  We have found that $3$ is a common factor of $m$ and $n$.

You failed to introduce $m$ or $n$ in your derivation and you are missing any words that would make this common divisor lead to a contradiction.  Perhaps you believe that a proper proof is just a barrage of equations.  It is not.  You need to introduce new symbols and explain how they relate.  For instance, a reader is right to ask "**Why** did you set $a = m/n$?  What is $m$?  What is $n$?  Are there any conditions among $m$ and $n$?"  Your demonstration is not a proof -- it is missing all the words that explain what you are doing and why.

Comment: This is a basic question which is asked in innumerable "intro to proofs" style classes.  It has been asked-and-answered on this site a comparable number of times.  Rather than providing another answer to this duplicate question (and others like it), please consider helping the asker by taking a couple of minutes to look for those duplicates *before* you answer.  This ensures that the asker gets an answer to their question, and helps to keep the site organized.

Comment: @XanderHenderson : The correct answer to this Question includes the extensive complaint about its "proof's" poor writing style.  OP has, in comments, asserted "My main goal was to know what do I need to do, and why do I need to do that."  I am certain this Answer is exactly responsive to this goal relative to this Question.  The other answers I found to this and minor variants of this question were not responsive to the specific deficiencies of this Question's proof.  Therefore, your comment does not improve this Answer.